# PHPUnit test code inside catch block

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, testing, phpunit, functional-testing

I have a Symfony controller using try...catch.
I use phpunit to test my application. I have searched but havent found a way how to test the code inside a catch exception. How can I force php unit to pretend that something went wrong and enters the catch block and test this as well?

ie:

```
 try {
      $foo = 1;
     } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->sendMail();
        return new Response();
    }
```

How can I tell phpunit to throw an \Exception so it will test code inside catch block of above?

Comment: if your controller throw an exception on some conditions, and you want test it, just simulate those conditions.

Comment: yeah, you can create those conditions in which your code will create exception.

Comment: What code do you have there exactly? The must something that throws exception in real application. And you need to mock this part to throw the exception. Still, it would be good if you could show us the code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, under those conditions, it will obviously not throw any exceptions, but consider the function your try/catch lies within. You need to unit test that function, and provide arguments that will cause it to fail, and catch.

For instance:

```
public function doStuff($argument) {
    try {
        $parsed = (int)$argument; //but what if $argument is a string with letters
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        //do stuff
    }
```

To test that an exception is thrown when you mess it up:

```
public function testDoStuff() {
    // get a mock of the class, let's just call it $mock
    // do some regular asserts if you want
    
    $this->setExpectedException('\Exception');
    $mock->doStuff("haha, you can't parse this");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you really have some complex stuff in your `catch` block you can move it to separate protected method of the controller and test it separately. You can easily access protected method outside of its class using reflection.

Comment: Please do not do this. Do not test protected methods. This is way to tightly coupled to the implementation details instead of the behavior details. This comes from the faulty assumption that you need to test every class individually. Instead of doing that, use TDD and only think about the contract you want to have with your little bundle of classes. You'll notice that your tests don't fail anymore when the refactoring is needed.